# nant: Custom messages for separate unit tests in single nant nunit2 target

Tags: c#, nunit, nant

We are using nant to build our source code and run unit tests (nunit 2.5). In nant build file, we have separate **nunit2** targets for different unit test assemblies.

```
<each message="Run Test 1" />
<nunit2 verbose="true">
    <formatter type="Plain" />
    <test assemblyname="Test1.dll" />
</nunit2>

<each message="Run Test 2" />
<nunit2 verbose="true">
    <formatter type="Plain" />
    <test assemblyname="Test2.dll" />
</nunit2>
```

On Team City build server it causes performance issue - each such target forces to load Nunit runner separately.

There is a possibility to merge tests in one **nunit2** target:

```
<nunit2 verbose="true">
    <formatter type="Plain" />
    <test assemblyname="Test1.dll" />
    <test assemblyname="Test2.dll" />
</nunit2>
```

However, output in such case is not explicit enough for us without **echo** statements.

Is there a way to have one **nunit2** target and specify custom messages for each test? Something like the following:

```
<nunit2 verbose="true">
    <formatter type="Plain" />
    <each message="Run Test 1" />
    <test assemblyname="Test1.dll" />
    <each message="Run Test 2" />
    <test assemblyname="Test2.dll" />
</nunit2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to have unit tests more verbose is to add labels attribute on nunit2 target

```
<nunit2 verbose="true" labels="true">
    <formatter type="Plain" />
    <test assemblyname="Test1.dll" />
    <test assemblyname="Test2.dll" />
</nunit2>
```

As a result, nant will output all run unit tests in the following format

```
***** Test1.Test1.Ctor_Test
***** Test2.Test2.Ctor_Test
Tests run: 2, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Time: 0.123 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```